# How can I know the true growth rate of index funds over a given interval?

Tags: index-fund, online-tools

There are many quotes flying around on the internet about the profitability of index funds. But is there a tool that would allow me to select an index fund, a purchase date and a sale date to calculate the **exact** profitability (with and without reinvestment)? Ideally it could also include a basic inflation calculation, but this could be done separately too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many DRIP calculators on the web that will achieve everything what you mentioned.  Here's one that I often use:

https://www.dividendchannel.com/drip-returns-calculator/

Here is a Portfolio Asset Allocation backtest tool, courtesy of Chris Rea:

https://www.portfoliovisualizer.com/backtest-portfolio